# How to sum two variables with the same name from two different python files?

Tags: python, variables, import

File 1:

```py
value = 10
```

File 2:

```py
value = 20
```

What I need in File 3:

```py
total = value_from_file1 + value_from_file2
```

How to implement that *(using the same variable names)*?

Comment: `from file1 import value as f1_value` `from file2 import value as f2_value` `total = f1_value + f2_value`

Comment: make File 1 and file 2 functions that return their values

Comment: Can you Elaborate ? We could understand nothing.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Thanks a lot, that works. would it be possible to turn this into a function?
for example: 
total = 0
files = ["file1","file2"]
for file in files:
total += value
return total

Comment: Don't think in terms of files. Think in terms of *modules*, and files are just one way (though by far the most common one) to define modules. Then read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html.

Comment: @YSH222, you can use [`import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module). `f1_value = getattr(import_module("file1"), "value")`. Normally you don't need this, but who knows, maybe you want to iterate over dozen of modules and collect some variables.